# Change the font size in a seaborn corrplot

Tags: plot, correlation, seaborn

My question is how to change the size of font in seaborn using correlation matrix I don't know why somehow the font is too large for me[image: see blow]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regrettably I don't think that's configurable, but what I would recommend is just to make the figure larger e.g.

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
sns.corrplot(df, ax=ax)
```

If that's not an option and you're primarily interested in the heatmap (not the numerical values), you could do

```
sns.corrplot(df, annot=False, sig_stars=False, diag_names=False)
```

Comment: Also if someone knows what rc parameter the `ax.text()` function reflects by default you could control it that way, but I cannot figure out which that might be.

Comment: the first line of codes works perfectly! Thank you so much! @mwaskom

Answer (score 13):

if you already have the correlation values in your data, you can use a heatmap and set up the size with "annot_kws", for example here setting it to 8.

```
sns.heatmap(data, vmin=data.values.min(), vmax=1, square=True, 
        linewidths=0.1, annot=True, annot_kws={"size":8})
```

and it would look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use the set method, modify the font scale parameter.

```
sns.set(font_scale=0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using set_context, then you can add a font scaling parameter along with the size of the plot.

```
sns.set_context("poster",font_scale=.7)
```

Answer (score 1):

i did this at this works quite well.

## enlarged the fig size to able to read it properly

```
 sns.set(style="white")
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 20))
sns.heatmap(bos.corr(),annot=True,annot_kws={"size":15})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following as one of the parameters in `seaborn.heatmap()`:

```
annot_kws={'size':12}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?